# Find and bash problems in recent Ubuntu versions

Tags: 11.04, bash, grep

I've been having a problem the last six months or so when combining searches in bash. The exact example is related to Python programming but would apply to any kind of detection/manipulation.

Suppose I want a list of all Python files in the directory where I am. This is easy:

```
find . -name '*.py'
```

Now, suppose I'm only interested in those Python files which contain the string "psycopg", e.g. because I want to transition from the old PostgreSQL access library *psycopg* to *psycopg2*. Still easy enough:

```
grep -l  psycopg `find . -name '*.py'`
```

Now, suppose I want to do a full list of these files to inspect their date stamps to see when I last touched them. I could also wish to open them in gedit, but let's stick to the list:

```
ls -l `!!`
```

which expands to

```
ls -l `grep -l  psycopg `find . -name '*.py'``
```

Now, what happens? Answer: Nothing. The bash prompt just hangs. Why is that? This may be a wrong way of doing things, but it used to work. I'm pretty sure it worked pre- Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04.

Comment: fyi: I tested your last command on hardy and lucid and both hang up too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the nested command substitution with backticks. `bash` first tries to execute `grep -l  psycopg` (which is between the first two backticks). But there's no filename - therefore it expects input on `stdin` (you can try this by entering `psycopg`).

You can avoid this problem by using the `$(command)` syntax for command substitutions:

```
grep -l  psycopg $(find . -name '*.py')
ls -l $(!!)
```

In this case it can be nested.

Answer (score 5):

Backticks do not nest. The first embedded command is `grep -l psycopg` which is going to listen on stdin for data because there are no filenames.

I'd say get used to using `$(this syntax)` instead of backticks because they do nest properly.

```
ls -l $(grep -l psycopg $(find . -name \*py))
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. Funny thing is that, as I observe, they _used_ to nest - or at least I think they did, I've been using this technique for years. But it's true, I acquired the habit of using backtips back from when I was still using tcsh. Must get used to $(...) instead.

Comment: Upvote.  Just a note: IIRC /bin/bash in default Ubuntu is in fact dash not real bash.  That could be part of why they no longer nest properly.

Comment: @aking1012, you mean `/bin/sh` is dash.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 5):

Do it in general the other way round, find the files, grep in them, and use finds ls:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec grep -q psycopg {} ";" -ls
```

special forms of output are possible (printf) and listed in the manpage of find.

Answer (score 1):

It is always wrong to have commands that output more than one filename inside `$()` or ``` `` ``` (command substitution). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for an explanation of why you shouldn't do that.

Also read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 on how to use find and deal with filenames properly.

And no,

```
ls -l `grep -l  psycopg `find . -name '*.py'``
```

couldn't possibly have worked in earlier versions either.

user unknown's answer shows a good and safe way to do the task you were asking about.